# How to show warnings in VSCode editor for a .cpp file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, g++, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to tweak VSC somehow to see GCC warnings in the text editor?
Refer to the screenshot below - it shows only errors in the console.

I'm using 1.43.2 version with C/C++ extension 0.26.3 installed.
Tried adding `-Wall` compiler flag to "args" in `tasks.json` but it didn't help.

[image]

Below are my settings:

```json
{
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 100,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning and errors are shown in Problem Panel.
You can see `Problems 4` on it.
You might need to install `Visual Studio IntelliCode` or `C++ Intellisense` to help you identify mistakes before compilation.

Comment: As I noted I'm already using C/C++ IntelliSense extension v0.26.3 (Microsoft), in addition, I just tried C++ Intellisense (Austin) and it didn't help. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Try `Visual Studio IntelliCode` because my VScode is highlighting all warning but TBH IDK which one of them is doing it.

Comment: Well I checked my extensions and I found that I am also using `C/C++ Clang Command Adapter` you can try that also if you want. I hope that it will work for you. Fingers Crossed.

Comment: Thank you, this extension did the trick. (C/C++ Clang Command Adapter)