# How to show warnings in VSCode editor for C/C++ files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have the same question asked here:
[How to show warnings in VSCode editor for a .cpp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872633/how-to-show-warnings-in-vscode-editor-for-a-cpp-file)
(Sorry I am new so can't add image)

Current version of VSCode somehow doesn't show any warnings for C/C++ code when typing the code. For example, using the same photo from above question . Basically `int foo = 1.22;` should give me a warning. Errors can show, but warnings don't...

The comments suggest using C/C++ clang command adapter but I don't know what it is. Is there an easy way to let warnings show up? Thanks!
Added : my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
        "compilerArgs": [
            "-Wall"
        ]
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

Comment: Maybe your c_cpp_properties.json is misconfigured.

Comment: Does [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mitaki28.vscode-clang) help?

Comment: But I am not sure how to install this "Clang" which is required by this extension...

Answer (score 1):

As @hjuston you have to add -Wconversion flag to the gcc args, your code should be this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
      "defines": ["_DEBUG", "UNICODE", "_UNICODE"],
      "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "cStandard": "gnu17",
      "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
      "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
      "compilerArgs": ["-Wall", "-Wconversion"]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I did this for my task.json and this works as you can see:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-Wconversion"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0" }
```

The result:

[image: task.jason Visual Studio Code Compiler]

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Wconversion` flag for gcc to have truncate warning. You have to add it into tasks.json in "args".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).