# can't see problems when I code in C using VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I code in C using VScode, I don't see any problems during the coding.
Here is a screenshot as an example:

[image]

As you can see, the editor doesn't tell me anything about the `printf22` that I wrote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show warnings in VSCode editor for a .cpp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872633/how-to-show-warnings-in-vscode-editor-for-a-cpp-file)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Put the minGW C compiler into the path of your system properly, then try to run

Comment: I have the right path but it still doesn't show any errors during the coding, only when I cimpile it shows me errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with VS extension "C/C++ Clang Command Adapter" or "Visual Studio IntelliCode" from VS code. That would give you warning before compilation.

Comment: I already have minGW, I tried to install now "Visual Studio IntelliCode" but I dont understand how to make it effect my code...

Comment: one of the tool if you have installed automatically warns you if you are typing something wrong with existing library functions etc

Comment: do you know how can I activate it?

Comment: Ok, I think you havent set env path in windows, Pls try to set the mingw bin path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho/44272417 , path would be like C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin