# Switch statements will not execute

Tags: c++

I have an assignment here that I've been working on for the past few hours and have been met with a problem. Whenever I compile and run the program in VS Code it throws me into an infinite loop where the text of the "menu" is printed repeatedly. I imagine this has something to do with the `for(;;){` loop at the beginning of the menu.

I've deleted the `for(;;){` statement at the beginning of the menu, and the continuous scrolling stopped, but I was unable to input any numbers (cases) and the program, essentially, just printed the menu and that was the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
    string name;
    float GPA;

public:
    string getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    float getGPA() const
    {
        return GPA;
    }

    void setName(string Name)
    {
        name = Name;
    }
    void setGPA(float gpa)
    {
        GPA = gpa;
    }

    Student(const string& name, float gpa)
        : name(name)
        , GPA(gpa)
    {
    }

    Student()
    {
    }

    void printDetails(Student s[], int n)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << "Name: " << setw(10) << "GPA: " << endl;
        cout << "=========================================" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << setw(20) << s[i].getName() << setw(10) << s[i].getGPA() << endl;
        }
    }

    float calcAverageGPA(Student s[], int n)
    {
        float avg = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            sum += s[i].getGPA();
        }
        avg = sum / n;
        return avg;
    }

    float getGPAbyName(Student s[], int n, string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            if (s[i].getName() == name)
                return s[i].getGPA();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void showListByGPA(Student s[], int n, float gpa)
    {

        cout << setw(20) << "Name: " << setw(10) << "GPA: " << endl;
        cout << "=========================================" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (s[i].getGPA() > gpa)
                ;
            cout << setw(20) << s[i].getName() << setw(10) << s[i].getGPA() << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int ch;
    Student s[50];
    string name;
    float GPA;
    float avg = 0;
    cout << "======================" << endl;
    cout << "(1): Add a student" << endl;
    cout << "(2): Print the details of a student" << endl;
    cout << "(3): Get the GPA of a Student by name." << endl;
    cout << "(4): Get names of students based on GPA." << endl;
    cout << "(6): Quit the program." << endl;
    cout << "Enter your option" << endl;
    switch (ch) {

    case '1':
        cout << "\nEnter student's name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter GPA" << endl;
        cin >> GPA;
        s[n] = Student(name, GPA);
        n++;
        break;

    case '2':
        s[0].printDetails(s, n);
        break;

    case '3':
        cout << "\nEnter the name of a student" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        GPA = s[0].getGPAbyName(s, n, name);
        if (GPA == -1) {
            cout << "\nStudent not found!" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "\nGPA is: " << endl;
        break;
    case '4':
        cout << "\nEnter GPA: " << endl;
        cin >> GPA;
        s[0].showListByGPA(s, n, GPA);
        break;
    case '5':
        avg = s[0].calcAverageGPA(s, n);
        cout << "\nAverage GPA: " << avg << endl;
        break;
    case '6':
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem resides in `main()`. I included the prior blocks of the program in case they were necessary to provide any suggestions.

Comment: 'ch' is defined as int but in switch case you were checking for character '1' instead of 1 directly.

Comment: In `main` you are referencin `ch` before a value is assigned to it. You didn't get a warning?

Comment: I have now modified it from where the case was looking for character 1, to number 1 and it prints the menu but only the menu. Any more ideas?

Comment: Please use a 'cin' statement to take the input for 'ch'. As i don't see one.

Comment: Where do you read in `ch`?

Comment: Unrelated to the above: `cin >> name;` is likely a bug. That is unless you tell the person to enter their first name only and make sure that they don't type a space (for people who have two first names)

Comment: I see that I left out where the program reads in the choice, pretty important, I'll say.

Comment: [Turn on compiler warnings!](https://godbolt.org/z/GoGx5fjnr)  You'd have saved yourself 20 minutes plus the time you spent typing the question.

Comment: Vitally important, I'd say.  Did you not find it curious that the program didn't wait for your choice after you asked for it?

Comment: Nate - Thanks for the tip. Do you know of a way to enable compiler warnings in VS Code or would you recommend using another IDE?

Comment: Mark - I did find it curious, but my thought process, as I'm only several months into coding, is to look for the worst case scenario and not the simplest answer.

Comment: @jacob: I don't use VSCode but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872633/how-to-show-warnings-in-vscode-editor-for-a-cpp-file might help.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously want to read in "ch".
You've also made this an int, and don't zero-initialize, which can cause some undefined behaviour if you don't set it beforehand.

The switch case should be

```
switch(X){
  case 1:
      // Code
      break;
}
```

etc..

The difference is "1" or 1. It evaluates an enumeration value, instead of strings.
For safety: you might want to add a case default, which is common practice.